# Check checkbox if inputbox has content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a function in jquery where, if a input text box has content, check the checkbox. if it is blank, uncheck the checkbox.

```
<form>
<input class="boxcheck" type="checkbox">
checkbox

<input class="boxtext" type="text">
text here 
</form>
```

The checkbox and the text input will in the beginning be empty but if a user decides to write something into the text box, the checkbox should be automatically checked if it isn't checked already by the user.

One other issue might be that a user will type something and this function will check the checkbox, but if a user goes back to the input box and deletes the contents in the input box, the checkbox should be unchecked automatically also.

Last problem I can think of would be if the user writes something into the text box, and this function checks the checkbox but the user for some odd reason unchecks the box, would it be possible to force check the checkbox again?

I have been playing around with the `keyup` and `prop` triggers but I am having absolutely no luck. I  am also very new to JavaScript.

The code I've been playing around is something like:

```
    $('input[text]').keyup(function(){
    if (this.value.length > 0) {
       $('input[name="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', false)
    } else {
})
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle with your problem.

Comment: Can you share some code that you have tried and let us know the issues that youhave face?

Comment: If the user isn't allowed to manually change the checkbox (as per your second last paragraph) then why have the checkbox at all?

Comment: $.trim($("input.boxtext").val()) == ''

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, perhaps it shouldn't be user editable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest handling the blur event in addition to keyup, because that covers any cases where the user changes the textbox value without the keyboard (copy/cut/paste/drags'n'drops/etc.), without needing to worry about which browsers do or don't let you handle clipboard events:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.boxtext").on("keyup blur", function() {
        $("input.boxcheck").prop("checked", this.value != "");
    });

    // don't allow user to manually change the checkbox
    $("input.boxcheck").click(function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WTVEn/

Note that although I've included code that stops the user changing the checkbox, if it can't be manually edited why do you need the checkbox at all?

Answer (score 1):

use [keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) function to check the val and conditions to check an uncheck the checkbox
tyr this

```
 $(".boxtext").keyup(function(){
   if($(this).val()!= ""){
     $('.boxcheck').prop('checked',true);
   }else{
     $('.boxcheck').prop('checked',false);
   }
})
```

**updated**

and for your last problem.. i think it will be better if you disable your checkbox.. so that user won't be able to uncheck...

```
 $('.boxcheck').prop('disabled',true);
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/EhpgX/2/)

Comment: this for some it reason works but I cannot enter anything into the input text box?

Comment: `I cannot enter anything into the input text box?` not getting you.. try this fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/EhpgX/1/

Comment: thanks! this works perfectly, my mistake for the earlier comment.

Comment: cool..:) welcome... happy coding.. and updated my answer for your last problem too.. check it out..

Comment: yes thanks! as people have pointed out, this makes more sense!

Comment: cheers have fun.. accept answer if u think this helped you..:)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $(".boxtext").change(function(){
   $('.boxcheck').attr('checked',true);
   if($(this).val()== ""){
     $('.boxcheck').attr('checked',false);
   }
});
```